# Grafana Loki recording rules

Tags: grafana-loki

How can we perform backfilling of recording rules in  grafana loki ,
i want to that  send data to prometheus remote write of a particular date.

I am trying to backfill data to prometheus from loki through recording rules.

like in prometheus we can perform through tsdb tool.